# How to add current user data to sub domain constraint rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Lets say I have below code in my action controller:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.has_not_created_website?
      themes_path
    else
      root_url(:subdomain=>resource.website.domain)
    end
  end
```

upon login redirects me to

```
http://webitdev.lvh.me:3000
```

But I want something like this:

```
http://webitdev.lvh.me:3000/websites/7/edit
```

I tried number of code and tricks but all in vain. I trying adding strings but it didnt work for me.

Comment: You have to redirect to edit method of websites controller. Like: `redirect_to edit_website_url(current_user)`

Comment: But I also want to add `:subdomain=>resource.website.domain` in it. @Abhi see more of it.

Comment: Pass it to the url like:- `redirect_to edit_website_url(:id => current_user, :subdomain => resource.website.domain)`

Comment: it says: `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in Devise::SessionsController#create ` @Abhi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`root_url` will generate the URL to the root path of your application, therefore `http://example.com`.

If you pass the subdomain parameter, it will be changed, but it will retain the path to the root.

The `subdomain` parameter can be used in any route generation, therefore if you want redirect the user to the website edit page under his subdomain, assuming the route is represented by the `edit_website_url(@website)`, just pass the subdomain parameter

```
edit_website_url(resource.website, subdomain: resource.website.domain)
```

Another common practice is to force the user to be under its subdomain at controller level (a before filter can check if the user is accessing the request via subdomain or not) and then always use relative paths

```
edit_website_path(resource.website)
```

In this way you will not have to specify the subdomain in each path generation.

Comment: why did you use `edit_website_url` instead of `edit_website_path`??

Comment: I explained that in my post, `_path` will generate a relative link. If you are already under that subdomain, there is no reason to generate an absolute path.